# Spotify cache on 5109MB on internal SD, 4464MB on external SD

Tags: external-sd, storage, internal-sd, cache, spotify

Spotify takes up about 10GB data on my phone. Half of this is used on the internal SD card, which is becoming a problem. I've had this problem before, have removed Spotify entirely, after which it started to use the external card. Since a while it has apparantly changed its mind, and now prefers the internal storage.

I don't mind that Spotify uses the internal storage for settings or for temporary cache, if that is necessary. I don't mind if that takes up 1GB, but I don't want this. Now I have to download 10GB music, which is a waste of time. Plus I lose the local settings, which albums I want to have locally.

When I look at the app specs in the Android settings menu, I see it reports 9.42 GB on the external card, and 1.48MB on the internal one. That seems like a bug?!

**Why does this happen and how can I force Spotify to use the external storage exclusively?**

Comment: Spotify is known to save extensive amounts of cache on all operating systems, saves money as music isn't downloaded from their servers on recurrent plays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting Spotify completely. I reinstalled it, and now have downloaded 3GB of data.

I usually download several playlists and albums to avoid downloading them repeatedly. I don't know why I ended up with two caches on internal and external SD, and I don't even know if both of them were used or if this is a bug.

Now the internal cache is empty or very small, and external is 3GB. This is still less than either of the old caches, but that's because Spotify forgets which albums I downloaded before, and the current set is not exactly the same.